# Matching multiple columns in one join

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

Table 1

```
item_name  |  assocID_1  |  assocID_2  |  assocID_3
ball            123           456           789
```

Table 2

```
assoc_key      assoc_value
123              red
456              white
789              blue
```

Am I able to create an output of:

```
ball    red   white  blue
```

With only one join? I understand I can just join the tables multiple times to easily get this result, but in my actual tables there are much more than 3 columns, and the app I'm using can only support 4 joins per query apparently.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it MySql, Oracle,Sql Server ??

Comment: Why not create a view that does the joining. That way you can select from a single "table" inside your app, avoiding that stupid limit.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about performance, you can do:

```
select t1.item_name,
       max(case when t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_1 then t2.assoc_value end),
       max(case when t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_2 then t2.assoc_value end),
       max(case when t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_3 then t2.assoc_value end)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.assoc_key in (t1.assocID_1, t1.assocID_2, t1.assocID_3)
group by t1.item_name;
```

You can also use subqueries.  If we assume that there is only one matching row in `table2`:

```
select t1.item_name,
       (select t2.assoc_value from table2 t2 where t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_1),
       (select t2.assoc_value from table2 t2 where t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_2),
       (select t2.assoc_value from table2 t2 where t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_3)
from table1 t1;
```

If there can be more than one match, you can arbitrarily choose one of them using aggregation functions:

```
select t1.item_name,
       (select max(t2.assoc_value) from table2 t2 where t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_1),
       (select max(t2.assoc_value) from table2 t2 where t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_2),
       (select max(t2.assoc_value) from table2 t2 where t2.assoc_key = t1.assocID_3)
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: Perfect. The subquery solution is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need a join here. You just need to look up which you can do in the SELECT statement directly. Here is an implementation in **SQL Server** (In Sample Data preparation code, if you are using version older than SQL Server 2016, please replace the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS with older way of doing the same)

**DDL and Test Data:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1
SELECT  item_name = 'ball'
        ,assocID_1 = 123
        ,assocID_2 = 456
        ,assocID_3 = 789
INTO    Table1   

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table2
SELECT  assoc_key       = 123
        ,assoc_value    = 'red'
INTO    Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT  assoc_key       = 456
        ,assoc_value    = 'white'
UNION ALL
SELECT  assoc_key       = 789
        ,assoc_value    = 'blue'

SELECT * FROM Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

**1. Brute Force Approach:**

```
SELECT  item_name   = T1.item_name
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 assoc_value FROM Table2 WHERE assoc_key = T1.assocID_1)
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 assoc_value FROM Table2 WHERE assoc_key = T1.assocID_2)
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 assoc_value FROM Table2 WHERE assoc_key = T1.assocID_3)
FROM    Table1 T1
```

**2. Dynamically Building the Query For Ease And Then Executing It. With this approach Number of Columns Would Not Be a Concern:**

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT    item_name   = T1.item_name '

SELECT  @SQL += '
,(SELECT TOP 1 assoc_value FROM Table2 WHERE assoc_key = T1.'+COLUMN_NAME+')'
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'  -- provide your proper schema name here
AND     TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
AND     COLUMN_NAME <> 'item_name' -- provide the columns you want to avoid doing lookups
ORDER   BY ORDINAL_POSITION

SET     @SQL+='
FROM    Table1 T1 '

PRINT   @SQL

EXEC    sp_executesql @statement=@SQL
```

**3. Combination of UNPIVOT, JOIN and PIVOT**

```
SELECT  item_name, [assocID_1], [assocID_2], [assocID_3]  -- you can dynamically build the select list like above example if you need
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  IQ.item_name, IQ.assocId, T2.assoc_value
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  UNP.item_name, UNP.assocId, UNP.Value
                        FROM    Table1 T1
                        UNPIVOT
                        (
                                Value FOR assocId IN ([assocId_1], [assocId_2], [assocId_3]) -- you can dynamically build this column list like above example if you need

                        ) UNP
                    ) IQ
                    INNER JOIN Table2 T2
                        ON IQ.Value = T2.assoc_key
        ) OQ
PIVOT
(
        MAX(assoc_value)
        FOR associd IN ([assocID_1], [assocID_2], [assocID_3]) -- you can dynamically build this column list like above example if you need
) PV
```

Comment: My bad. Updated the DBMS name in my answer. Also, I agree that I should have asked for the DBMS name in comment first.

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_name, decode(ASSOCID_1,(select assocID_1 from t1  ), (select assoc from t2 where assoc_key =aa.assocID_1),null ) ,
                                    decode(ASSOCID_2,(select assocID_2 from t1  )  , (select assoc from t2 where assoc_key =aa.assocID_1),null ),
                                    decode(ASSOCID_3,(select assocID_3 from t1  ), (select assoc from t2 where assoc_key =aa.assocID_1),null ) from t1 aa
```

Comment: You should mention that this is a solution for Oracle

Comment: please try this one    :)